# Как реализовать ajax запрос?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть таблица

```
`echo "<td>
<form action='/teacher/saveocenka' id ='form1' method='Post'><input type='hidden' value='".$row['ID']."' name='studid'>
    <input type='hidden' value='1' name='day'>
    <select name='ocenka' required id='idcat'><option selected>".$row['C1']."</option><option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
<option value='Н'>H</option>    
    </select><input type='submit' value='ok'> </form></td>";}`
```

таких 31, при нажатии на кнопку "ОК" отправляется данные и обновляет в таблице БД. Как можно реализовать это через ajax? Если через ajax то я должен дать id для каждой формы и должен писать скрипт для каждой формы? их у меня будет 31[image: имеет такой вид]

Answer (score 2):

Что бы избежать перечисления id каждой формы добавьте произвольный класс к форме например `.ajax-form` и привяжитесь к [событию](https://api.jquery.com/submit/#submit-handler) `.submit()`.

Что бы взять все данные из формы и передать их в ajax запрос используйте [функцию](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) `serialize()`.

Так же не забудьте [использовать](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) `.preventDefault()` что бы не срабатывала стандартная отправка формы.

**Пример кода**

```js
$(".ajax-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // избегаем отправки формы
  
  var form = $(this);
  var url = form.attr('action');
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize(), // Сериализуем элементы формы.
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data); // показать ответ от скрипта php.
    }
  });

});
```

[Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/7678419)